# how do i stop the interval if a certain condition is met

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can i stop the interval if !status === "send". I have a function that checks a poll response url so i want it to stop when payment status changes.

```
module.exports = (pnInstance, pollUrl) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      pnInstance
        .pollTransaction(pollUrl)
        .then(({ status }) => {
          console.log(status);

          if (!status === "sent") {
            console.log("changed", status);
            stop();
            resolve({ status });
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    }, 1000);

    const stop = () => clearInterval(interval);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a function expression to a `const` variable ensures that the function definition is not `Hoisted` because you cannot change the const.

Try this :

```js
module.exports = (pnInstance, pollUrl) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      pnInstance
        .pollTransaction(pollUrl)
        .then(({ status }) => {
          console.log(status);

          if (!status === "sent") {
            console.log("changed", status);
            stop();
            resolve({ status });
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    }, 1000);

     function stop(){
       clearInterval(interval);
     }
  });
};
```

Comment: thank you very much. Its keeping on running even after the !status === sent